# Почему переменная обнуляется

Tags: python, python-3.x

переменная `Balance` обнуляется,когда через переменную `ammount` она должна пополнатся

```
call_time = int(input("Enter the cost of 1 min of a phone call (RUB):"))
SMS = float(input("Enter the cost of 1 SMS(RUB):"))
mb_traffic = int(input("Enter the cost of 1 MB of internet Traffic (RUB):"))



def main(call_time=call_time,SMS=SMS,mb_traffic=mb_traffic):

    while 1:

        Balance = 0


        print("Current balance:",Balance,"\n")

        menu = """
        1 top-up
        2 make a call
        3 send a SMS
        4 surf web
        5 exit

        """
        print(menu)
        input_menu = int(input("You choice:"))

        print("Current balance:",Balance,"\n")



        if input_menu < 1:
            print("Unsupported action Try again!")
            return main()
        if input_menu == 1:
            amount = int(input("Enter the amount(RUB):"))
            Balance += amount
            print(Balance)
            return main()
        elif input_menu == 2:
            call_min = int(input("Enter call duration (min):"))
            Combing = call_time * call_min
            if Combing > Balance:
                print("Could not send all data due to insufficient funds")
                return main()
            else:
                print("You were charged ", Combing, "for the call")
                Combing_Balance = Balance - Combing; Balance += Combing_Balance
                return main()
        elif input_menu == 3:
            word = input("Enter the message to send:")
            sms_charged = word.count(",")
            sms_combing = int(SMS * sms_charged)
            if sms_combing > Balance:
                print("Could not send all data due to insufficient funds")
                return main()
            else:
                print("You were charged",sms_combing,"for",sms_charged,"SMS")
                Combing_balance = Balance - sms_combing; Balance += Combing_Balance
                return main()
        elif input_menu == 4:
            MB = input("Enter the amount of data transfered (MB):")
            Combing_ethenet = mb_traffic * MB
            if Balance < Combing_ethenet:
                print("Could not send all data due to insufficient funds")
                return main()
            else:
                print("Surfed ethernet :D")
                Combing_balance = Balance - Combing_ethenet; Balance += Combing_Balance







main()
```

Comment: Вот в этом проблема `return main()`. У вас просто заново все начинается. Лучше создайте цикл внутри `main` и на `5` делайте из него выход

Comment: @gil9red у меня до этого стоял цикл `while` и я тоже думал то что из-за него все сбрасывается.С циклом тоже не работает

Comment: Как и написал gil9red, каждый раз при вызове main в цикле обнуляется баланс. Если нужно, чтобы баланс сохранялся - создайте его за пределами цикла и обнуляйте по определенной команде.

Comment: @kombat 
    while 1:
        Balance = 0
Каждый раз Balance сбрасывается в 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в строке `return main()`. Во-первых, у Вас получается рекурсивный вызов функции, причём без крайнего случая. Во-вторых, вызываемая рекурсивно функция `main()` имеет собственное пространство имён, где `Balance` - уже новая переменная, и она снова принимает значение `0`. Более того, `Balance` обнуляется каждую итерацию цикла. Необходимо вынести первоначальное присваивание `Balance = 0` за пределы цикла (перед ним).

В Вашем случае будет уместно использовать `continue` там, где сейчас стоит `return main()`. Инструкция `continue` вынуждает сразу перейти к следующей итерации цикла, что Вам и нужно. И не забудьте добавить выход из цикла (`break`) при выборе опции 5 в меню.
Исправленный вариант кода показан ниже

```
call_time = int(input("Enter the cost of 1 min of a phone call (RUB):"))
SMS = float(input("Enter the cost of 1 SMS(RUB):"))
mb_traffic = int(input("Enter the cost of 1 MB of internet Traffic (RUB):"))


def main(call_time=call_time,SMS=SMS,mb_traffic=mb_traffic):
    Balance = 0

    while 1:
        print("Current balance:",Balance,"\n")

        menu = """
        1 top-up
        2 make a call
        3 send a SMS
        4 surf web
        5 exit
        """
        print(menu)
        input_menu = int(input("You choice:"))

        print("Current balance:",Balance,"\n")

        if input_menu < 1:
            print("Unsupported action Try again!")
            continue
        if input_menu == 1:
            amount = int(input("Enter the amount(RUB):"))
            Balance += amount
            print(Balance)
            continue
        elif input_menu == 2:
            call_min = int(input("Enter call duration (min):"))
            Combing = call_time * call_min
            if Combing > Balance:
                print("Could not send all data due to insufficient funds")
                continue
            else:
                print("You were charged ", Combing, "for the call")
                Combing_Balance = Balance - Combing; Balance += Combing_Balance
                continue
        elif input_menu == 3:
            word = input("Enter the message to send:")
            sms_charged = word.count(",")
            sms_combing = int(SMS * sms_charged)
            if sms_combing > Balance:
                print("Could not send all data due to insufficient funds")
                continue
            else:
                print("You were charged",sms_combing,"for",sms_charged,"SMS")
                Combing_balance = Balance - sms_combing
                Balance += Combing_Balance
                continue
        elif input_menu == 4:
            MB = input("Enter the amount of data transfered (MB):")
            Combing_ethenet = mb_traffic * MB
            if Balance < Combing_ethenet:
                print("Could not send all data due to insufficient funds")
                continue
            else:
                print("Surfed ethernet :D")
                Combing_balance = Balance - Combing_ethenet
                Balance += Combing_Balance
                continue
        elif input_menu == 5:
            break

main()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я пробавал методом `return input_menu` но программа выходила и тогда я решил сделать рекурсию, но та она у меня все сбраывала